# E: unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full

Tags: ros, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have followed the ROS site's instructions on installing ROS indigo on Trusty Ubuntu through virtualbox, but I get this error. I know indigo is now released, which was the previous problem for a couple of questions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188732/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-full/) by [joshpj1](https://answers.ros.org/users/19916/joshpj1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-08-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-08-03**:
Did you add the ROS repository to your list of repos

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-11-20**:
More specifically, can you paste the result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'` command?

**Comment by [preto](https://answers.ros.org/users/29520/preto/) on 2017-02-28**:
@130s   Not sure if this question is still active but worth a shot. I tried installing jade on my 14.04 and it is not allowing me to setup my sources. Whenever I try the command to setup it up as the tutorial says my terminal simply breaks a new line and does nothing.

**Comment by [preto](https://answers.ros.org/users/29520/preto/) on 2017-02-28**:
And cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list does the same... breaks a line and does nothing, forcing me to Crtl + C

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-01**:
@preto please open a new question. Comment sections is not supposed to ask a new one (and you won't get as much attention).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is weird if you followed the instructions. Did you do all of those steps?

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteMakesThings](https://answers.ros.org/users/24332/petemakesthings/) on 2015-10-07**:
Thanks, I'm newer to Linux so reading the instructions I wasn't sure what the commands for each step were. So writing them out as commands really helped. It's installing for me now.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-10-14**:
glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same thing happens to me. I followed the steps strictly, but it still can not be found.

---

Originally posted by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) with karma: 25 on 2014-11-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sunoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/22248/sunoval/) on 2015-04-23**:
I mistaken "packages.ros.org" as "package.ros.org" and had the same error message. After fixed it, it installed smoothly. check urs

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the same error. I tried the 4 steps and when I do  :

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full

I get the error.

I am copy-pasting the command on the http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu, hence do not see any typos happening.

When I check for the ros-latest.list, I get the following output:

....@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu vivid main

Let me know what might be going on.

I am running ubuntu on vmware player

---

Originally posted by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) with karma: 35 on 2015-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-08-23**:
you should use Ubuntu 14.04 for ROS indigo (trusty tahr). Or install Ros Jade on Ubuntu 15.04 (vivid)